# usage of interface in the android development

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

Hi friends I want to know how to use interfaces in the android development I had searched everywhere, but there is no clear document to know how to use an interface in our android development

Comment: An interface is something from Java. It is not tied specifically to Android.

Comment: Agreed - interfaces are specific to the language, in this case Java if you're doing it natively. A quick Google search found this http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/02/07/write-interfaces-java-android/

Comment: but how to combine them?

Comment: i had looked into that link but not clearly enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces are not really an Android thing per se, it's more a Java thing in general (not even a Java thing for that matter).

In Android you'll usually find interfaces being used as a way to attach methods to events that happen in the UI. Here's an example:

Say we have a `Button` called `mButton`.
**Java 7**

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do whatever you want in here
        }
    }
);
```

**Explanation of what just happened**
`View.OnClickListener` is an `interface` with a single method: `void onClick(View v)`. I essentially instantiated a class that automatically implements the `View.OnClickListener` and that class overrides the `onClick` method (this is known as an *anonymous class*). The `Button` then calls the `onClick` method whenever you click on the `Button`.
Hope that helps :).

**Java 8**
Note that with Java 8 we can now use lambda functions instead to avoid the great [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_%28programming%29) (SO much better) and just general over verbosity:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    // Do whatever you want here
});
```

Interfaces are also really useful for sharing method names across different classes (since you can only inherit from a single class in Java). E.g. [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) is a good example of this.

Couple of links if you want to know more about interfaces in Android/Java:
[Input events in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)
[Explanation of why we use interfaces](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/131334/166344)

Comment: thanks for your explanation helped me so that i can search for examples. so that i can understand how to use so that i can learn it perfectly

Comment: No worries mate :)